# move cvs repository from one server to another

Tags: version-control, cvs

I need to move CVS repository from one server to another. Currently my repository is on external hard disk. So I believe I do not need to copy code from one server to another. Both the servers are same OS and have same version of cvsnt on them. How should I go about doing this task? Currently I just disconnected the hard disk from the old server and connected it to new server.

I opened control panel item of CVS NT and could see repository configuration. There is an add button which I believe creates a new repository. What should I do to change the server name in the CVS configuration and what should clients do to something analogous to svn relocate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server side it is simple to move the repository.  Just move the repository to the new server.  Ensure the server is serving it.  This can be done by checking out the project or a portion of it.  If you are using a graphical tool to create the repository, it may be simplest to create a new repository, and then replace it with the moved repository.

On the client side you need to recursively replace the contents of the CVS/Root file in each directory with the new root.  You may need to be careful doing so as users may have other roots.  It is valid to have different Roots nested in the same tree.

Comment: This is the exact procedure that I use when I have to move a CVS repository. Never had problems.

Comment: Isnt there anything on client side for CVS something like SVN relocate? Do we have to manually change this in all root files?? Isn't that a bit tedious? If there is no way, I probably should ask all my team members to do it.

Comment: and sorry I cant vote up ur answer since my rep score is low.

Comment: Fixing the root can be done with a relatively trivial Perl script.  In the past I have installed Active Perl on a network share along with the script.  I have seen published scripts, but finding and vetting an appropriate script seems to take longer than developing a custom script.  You may be able to mount the new directory on the old location to ease migration.  This works well on Linux, but I don't know how Windows will handle it.